# MySQL can't create table with foreign key

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

```
CREATE  TABLE `assessmentbookdb`.`MCQs` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `MCQAnswer` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL ,
  `QuestionID` INT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
  INDEX `QuestionID` (`QuestionID` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `QuestionID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`QuestionID` )
    REFERENCES `assessmentbookdb`.`Question` (`QuestionID` )
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Message Log:

ERROR 1005: Can't create table 'assessmentbookdb.mcqs' (errno: 121)
SQL Statement:

```
CREATE  TABLE `assessmentbookdb`.`MCQs` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `MCQAnswer` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL ,
  `QuestionID` INT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
  INDEX `QuestionID` (`QuestionID` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `QuestionID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`QuestionID` )
    REFERENCES `assessmentbookdb`.`Question` (`QuestionID` )
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
    ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Answer (score 6):

Double-check that:

- The key's name is unique
- The two keys you're coupling have the exact same datatype (here: `INT NOT NULL`), even signedness
- The referencing fields actually exist

Comment: Yet in a different answer you write "*Oh ya, I have the same constraint name.*" - so you didn't check it.

Comment: As this post recommends, make sure they're the same signedess.  I checked for the exact same datatypes - both where bigint(20) - but one was signed and the other was unsigned.  I made them the same and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

based on googling i would assume that you have a  constraint that exists with the same name that you try to add a constraint with. It might be that you didnt delete an old constraint from the old version of the table or something.

Comment: Oh ya, I have the same constraint name. Thx a lot

Answer (score 0):

> table creation failed because a foreign key constraint was not correctly formed

Somehow your foreign key is not correct. This can be if the table you are refering does not exist yet.

Comment: Question table exist already and QuestionID is the primary key of Question Table. I can't find what's wrong

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-error-codes.html#c9317) and try to not give a name to your constraint.

Answer (score -1):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

InnoDB supports foreign keys, which let you cross-reference related data across tables, and foreign key constraints, which help keep this spread-out data consistent. The syntax for an InnoDB foreign key constraint definition in the CREATE TABLE or ALTER TABLE statement looks like this:

```
 [CONSTRAINT [symbol]] FOREIGN KEY
 [index_name] (index_col_name, ...)
REFERENCES tbl_name (index_col_name,...)
[ON DELETE reference_option]
[ON UPDATE reference_option]

 reference_option:
RESTRICT | CASCADE | SET NULL | NO ACTION
```